# Download template from Sharepoint, save it, close it and then open it via folder where it is saved

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I've my templates on a sharepoint and download them. I want it to first save on E.G., my desktop and then close the file and then open the file from the desktop and then do everything from there.

My current code looks like this:

```
Public Function CH05_Generate()

Dim WordApp As Word.Application
Dim Doc As Word.Document
Dim WordPath As String

WordPath = "Path to the sharepoint"

Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set Doc = WordApp.Documents.Add(WordPath)

With Doc
    .FormFields("text").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!Kommentar
    .FormFields("S3").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q1
    .FormFields("S4").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q2
    .FormFields("S5").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q3
    .FormFields("S6").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q4
    .FormFields("S7").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q5
    .FormFields("S8").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q6
    .FormFields("S9").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q7
    .FormFields("S10").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q8
    .FormFields("S11").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q9
    .FormFields("S12").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q10
    .FormFields("S13").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q11
    .FormFields("S14").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q12
    .FormFields("S15").CheckBox.Value = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q13
    .FormFields("S16").CheckBox.Value = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q14
    .FormFields("S17").CheckBox.Value = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q15
    .FormFields("S18").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q16
    .FormFields("S19").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q17
    .FormFields("S20").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q18
    .FormFields("S21").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q19
    .FormFields("S22").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q20
    .FormFields("S23").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q21
    .FormFields("S24").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q22
    .FormFields("S25").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q23
    .FormFields("S26").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q24
    .FormFields("S27").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q25
    .FormFields("S28").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q26
    .FormFields("S29").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q27
    .FormFields("S30").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q28
    .FormFields("S31").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q29
    .FormFields("S32").Result = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q30
    .FormFields("S33").CheckBox.Value = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q31
    .FormFields("S34").CheckBox.Value = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q32
    .FormFields("S35").CheckBox.Value = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q33
    .FormFields("S36").CheckBox.Value = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q34
    .FormFields("S37").CheckBox.Value = Forms![TD-E-PM200-CH05]!sub.Form!Q35
End With

WordApp.visible = True
WordApp.Activate
WordApp.ActiveDocument.Protect wdAllowOnlyFormFields, True

End Function
```

So I want all the `.FormFields` to be done in the file that has been open on my desktop and not the Sharepoint.